# Finding out what Registry keys have been changed C#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm currently in the process of developing and researching the feasibility of creating a small application to monitor personal preference changes within the registry.

Where I've just started working are using mandatory profiles on the users meaning personal preferences aren't saved. The idea of this project is to monitor personal preference changes, and record them to a file every minute or so while using minimal resources.

So far I've created a small program which monitors for changes of the registry and reports that a change has been made using: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registrymonitor.aspx

But what I need it to really do is report back to me to say what registry keys have acctually been changed, at the moment it just says a change has been made but not to which key. If I can monitor the changes and get it to return which key has been changed I'll be ok with the rest.

So is there any way of doing this in C#? Or should I be looking at other languages?

I can't use WMI or other systems like that as the information I'm trying to retrieve is stored in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER part of the registry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)? (it replaced RegMon)

Comment: Yes something like that, is it able to monitor specific keys and export change values to another file?

I had a quick look and was going to investigate further this week.