# Monitoring added registry key by a certain process (using c#)

Tags: c#, registry

Is there any way, using c#, to monitor which registry key has been added by a certain process?
the important thing for me is to know the key name (path) and not just the fact that a key
has been added.
thanks

Comment: No, not by a 'certain process'.

Comment: See if this link helps you get a better idea of what you are trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application

Comment: **registery** key. not keyboard key.

Comment: My apologize looking at another post.

Comment: See if this is more along the lines you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614088/finding-out-what-registry-keys-have-been-changed-c-sharp?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you cannot do this in C# only.

However, I can guide you to a solution (but it is quite advanced, though)

Registery is handled by winapi calls (which are native functions).
For instance, one of them is:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static int RegSetValueEx(SafeRegistryHandle hKey, string lpValueName, int Reserved, RegistryValueKind dwType, string lpData, int cbData);
```

Thus, knowing when a process sets a registry value is equivalent to know when this function is called.

You can inject a process and "hack" a function (i.e. replace an existing function with your own implementation) using [easy hook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

Your solution would be to use this library, hook the process you want and replace RegSetValueEx (in advapi32.dll) with a custom implementation that would only forward the call to the real implementation, and notify you when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it took me a step forward.

Comment: suppose I want to create an application that monitor when the function RegSetValueEx is been triggered and which parameters it gets, how can I do that ?